# What is the purpose of a restricting the type of generic in a method?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm having a hard time understanding why it would be beneficial to do something like this: (Sample is a class)

```
static void PrintResults<T>(T result) where T : Sample
```

Wouldn't it be better to to just pass Sample into the method?

```
 static void PrintResults (Sample result)
```

Comment: For things that are passed to methods the benefit is indeed rather small. For things that are returned again it helps a bit more because the consumer doesn't need to cast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend avoiding generic types where non-generic syntax works, such as the example you gave. However, there are other useful cases.

For example, specifying the return type generically:

```
static T Create<T>() where T: Sample, new()
{
    return new T();
}

// Calling code
Sample sample = Create<Sample>();
```

instead of

```
static object Create()
{
    return new Sample();
}

// Calling code
Sample sample = (Sample) Create();
```

You can also use templates to place multiple restrictions on a type. For example:

```
static T Create<T>() where T: IMyInterface, new()
{
    return new T();
}

interface IMyInterface {} 
class MyClass : IMyInterface { }

// Calling code.
MyClass myClass = Create<MyClass>();
```

This allows the generic creation of a new type that implements a specific interface and has a generic constructor. Also:

```
static void DoSomething<T>(T t) where T: IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2
{
    t.MethodOnIMyInterface1();
    t.MethodOnIMyInterface2();
}

interface IMyInterface1 
{
    void MethodOnIMyInterface1();
}     
interface IMyInterface2
{
    void MethodOnIMyInterface2();
}     
class MyClass: IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2 
{ 
    // Method implementations omitted for clarity
}

// Calling code
MyClass myclass'
DoSomething(myclass);  // Note that the compiler infers the type of T.
```

Where you can require multiple interfaces on a single parameter without (1) creating a new type that implements all these interfaces and (2) requiring parameters to be of that type.

As @dcastro points out in his/her answer, generic types can also tell the compiler to require types are the same. For example:

```
static void DoSomething<T>(T t1, T t2) where T: MyType
{
    // ...
}

class MyType {}
class MyType1: MyType {} 
class MyType2: MyType {} 

// Calling code
MyType1 myType1;
MyType2 myType2;
DoSomething<MyType>(myType1, myType2);
```

Where the compiler requires that t1 and t2 are the same type but can be any type that inherits `MyType`. This is useful in automated unit testing frameworks, such as NUnit or MSTest, for generic equality and comparison checks.

Comment: The bit at the end about forcing the same types is not correct.  Any of these would compile just fine `DoSomething<MyType>(mytype1, mytype2); DoSomething((MyType)mytype1, mytype2);` ...

Comment: @akton thanks for the detailed answer. I actually appreciated all of the answers provided! I realize I didn't give the best example to work with but you managed to answer the question well. Thanks again!

Comment: @Brandon The question is not whether things will compile. Generic types (1) make code easier to read (although not in the OP's case) and (2) move more checking into compile time from runtime (usually by replacing casts). In the specific case, this is not the best example but is good enough to answer the OP's question.

Comment: Also, if we had had `where T : ISample` for `ISample` an interface, that would allow us to use the method for both `struct` and `class` "values" of `T`. And when we call members of the interface `ISample` on the method argument `result`, the cool thing is that even when `T` is a value-type (struct), we do not get boxing when we call the `ISample` members (methods etc.) on `result`. If the struct has explicit interface implementations, we can even call them without boxing the struct.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers are offering explanations of the usefulness of generics involving interfaces that don't really seem to address your actual question.

Truth is, for the example you posted, there is no benefit to using a generic method.  It is actually *worse* because it will cause multiple implementations of the same function to be generated and ever slightly increase the code size at runtime.

Comment: I do not think what you mention about "multiple implementations" applies in his case because `Sample` is necessarily a reference type (in fact he tells us it is a `class`). For reference types, there are not "multiple implementations". Other than that, you may be right there is not much benefit in his particular scenario. We do get an extra type `T` (which is a compile-time type whence `typeof(T)` is not necessarily identical to `result.GetType()`). The method can use that type, for example `var config = HelperClass<T>.GetConfig();` or something.

Answer (score 2):

In voids you could allways use an interface as a parameter to make multiple types work, so generics arent often useful here.

Only exceptions are the constraints on generics. And by that i dont mean something like 
    where T: IA, IB
since this could be done by an interface aswell that both implements IA and IB. This will get tiresome at some point however since you will need more and more interfaces. So lets look ath the "special constraints" class and new

```
public void AddNew(List<T> items) where T : new
{
    items.Add(new T());
}
```

and class which is useful if the method mutates its parameter, which wont work for structs

```
static void IncA<T>(T item) where T: class, IA
{
    item.A++;
}
```

The real power of generics is when methods have a generic return type or generic classes like List <T>. You dont want to implement a new class for every List you will need.